# Problems with traversing table using DOM

Tags: javascript

I managed to fix some trouble I was having with traversing through table rows with DOM using only JavaScript but ran into 2 hurdles. I'm trying to create a table, where each row will have a set of buttons to move that particular row up, down or remove it. I was able to successfully use the .replaceChild method but it replaces the row instead of just swapping them. When I tried .moveRow, I keep getting an error saying the HTML table section does not have that method. I run into the same problem when trying to swap the current row with the row below. Any suggestions?

```
function up(x){

        // var tableBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]; // tried it with tableBody and it still didn't work
        var table = x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        var tableRow = x.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
        var previousRow = x.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.cloneNode(true);
        table.replaceChild(tableRow,x.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling);

    }

    function down(x){
        var table = x.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        var tableRow = x.parentNote.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
        var belowRow = x.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.cloneNode(true);
        table.moveRow(tableRow,x.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling);
    }
```

My buttons:

```
<table id="table1" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th> <th>Column 2</th> <th>Column 3</th> <th>Column 4</th> 
            </tr>   
            <tr id="enterData">
                <td id="buttons">
                    <input type="button" value="Up" onclick="up(this)" />
                    <input type="button" value="Down" onclick="down(this)" /> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Did you try [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore)? And why are you cloning rows, don't you just want to move them around with those functions?

Comment: Let's see this link http://help.dottoro.com/ljuikjpk.php, moveRow seems not to be cross-browser. Btw, try to 'dry' your code, avoiding to call each time, x.parentNode.parentNode. It will be clearer for you

Comment: @bfavaretto: I didn't try insertBefore, although now that I look at it, I think it would solve my problem. I was cloning the rows because I wanted to copy the values from that row and wasn't sure if it would work without doing that.

Comment: So you should try Musa's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insertBefore` to move up or down the rows and `appendChild` for the last row, also I use *ElementSibling to avoid text node issues but that might cause compatibily issues.

```
function up(x){
    var row = x.parentNode.parentNode;
    var table = row.parentNode;
    //Don't move up over the header
    if (row.previousElementSibling && row.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling){
        table.insertBefore(row,row.previousElementSibling);
    }
}
function down(x){
    var row = x.parentNode.parentNode;
    var table = row.parentNode;
    //can't use insertBefore for last row.
    if (row.nextElementSibling && row.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling){
        table.insertBefore(row,row.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling);
    }
    else{
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyaBQ/1)

Comment: Thank you very much! Is .nextSiblingElement a typo and meant to be .nextElementSibling or is it a different method?